# echo data from http request as you get them and keep requesting more

Tags: php, api, http, asynchronous, curl

I managed to get a working code for now but it's not what I want,
the http call return 2 results every response, and it keep doing the same call as long as there is more results, this work for now but for some results it could take a very long time because there is more than 100 results. is there a way to echo the results as soon as you get them and keep calling for more results?

I never worked with php sorry if the code look bad.

```
<?php
$par = $_GET['par1'];
$results = array();
htcall($results, $par);
echo $results;

function htcall(&$results, $par)
{
    $done = false;
    $lid = -1;

    while ($done == false) {
        inner($par, $lid, $done, $results);
    }

    echo 'done.';
}

function inner($par, &$lid, &$done, &$results)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $url = 'http url';
    if ($lid == -1) {
        $body = "id=" .  $par;
    } else {
        $body = "id=" .  $par. "&lid=" . $lid;
    }
    $headers = [
        'Host: host',
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    ];

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $resp = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($e = curl_error($ch)) {
        echo 'Request Error:' . $e;
        curl_close($ch);
    } else {
        $decoded = json_decode($resp, true);
        foreach ($decoded as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
                    if ($value1['title'] == 'noMore') {
                        $done = true;
                    } else {
                        $lid = $value1['id'];
                        array_push($results, $value1['title']);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        curl_close($ch);
    }
}
?php>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you're echoing your data only after everything's done, not while it's done. For that to happen, you'll need to re-structure your code a bit by separating what each function is concerned with - or needs to be concerned with, rather.

For example, you need a function to issue POST requests, but it doesn't have to know anything about the data itself - it just needs to send requests and receive responses. It doesn't even have to know how to deal with errors:

```php
/**
 * Send POST requests to given URL with given data. 
 *
 * @return array
 */
function http_post(string $url, string $data): array {

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $error    = curl_error($ch);

    curl_close ($ch);

    // Just return right away, do not be concerned with anything else
    return $error ? [false, $error] : [true, $response];
}
```

In the same spirit, let's factor out how the query string is build. It's not much, but it helps in the long run, for example when your queries grow in complexity. And it's definitely a concern of its own:

```php
/**
 * Builds a query string based on the given data.
 * 
 * @return String
 */
function build_query_string($id, $lid): string {

    return ($lid == -1) ? "id={$id}" : "id={$id}&lid={$lid}"; 
}
```

What's left is collecting your data. Though there's plenty of room to factor out more, let's do it in one go - and, most importantly as per your question, let's try to give immediate feedback after each request:

```php
/**
 * Triggers POST requests, collects & evaluates the respective responses.
 * 
 * @return array
 */
function collect_post_data($url, $id, $lid) {

    $stack        = [];
    $query_string = build_query_string($id, $lid);

    while (true) {

        // Get & evalute $response 
        
        list($success, $response) = http_post($url, $query_string);

        if (!$success) {

            return $stack; // Or thrown an error, or...
        }

        // Best move this part to a separate function, too

        $response = json_decode($response, true);

        foreach ($response as $key => $value) {

            // Build a new query string, 
            // set $continue to false if $value1['title'] == 'noMore', ...
        }

        $stack[] = $response;

        // Give some feedback
         
        var_dump($response); // If this is part of a command-line script, var_dump()
                             // happens right away. 

        if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') { // But if this is part of a website/webapp...

            ob_flush(); //...than we have to flush the output buffer...
            flush();    //...which is a two-step-process, cf. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php
        }

        // Mock an exit condition

        if (count($stack) > 10) {

            return $stack;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, we can kick-start the whole thing with:

```php
$id  = 1; // Probably data coming in...
$lid = 1; // ...from somewhere else

// Executes a bunch of requests & var_dumps() the results along the way
$results = collect_post_data('https://httpbin.org/post', $id, $lid);
```